# How to prevent component from updating service

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am new to Angular 4 and am trying to set up a service that has some data that should not be able to be edited by any of the components it provides data to. For example, here is a simplified version of my service:

```
@Component({
  providers: [ArgumentService]
})

@Injectable()
export class ArgumentService {
  pronouns: Object[];
  constructor() {

   this.pronouns = [{'type': "1SG", 'value': 'n', "series": "I"},
                    {'type': "2SG", 'value': 'm', "series": "I"},
                    {'type': "1SG", 'value': "'y", "series": "II"},
                    {'type': "2SG", 'value': 'n', "series": "II"},
                    {'type': "1SG", 'value': "'nii'y", "series": "III"},
                    {'type': "2SG", 'value': "'niin", "series": "III"}];

  }

  getPronouns(){
    return this.pronouns
  }

}
```

The array of objects should not change. However, the example function in the component below changes the first object in the array:

```
import { Sentence } from '../sentence.model'
import { VerbService, ArgumentService } from '../../services/'
import { RadioButtonComponent } from '../radio-button/radio-button.component'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-sentence',
  templateUrl: './sentence.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../../bootstrap.min.css', './sentence.component.scss', '../app.component.scss'],
  providers: [VerbService, ArgumentService]
})

export class SentenceComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public verbService: VerbService, public argumentService: ArgumentService) {

    this.example()

  }


  example(){
    let arg = this.argumentService.getPronouns()[0]
    arg['position'] = 'S'
    console.log(this.argumentService.getPronouns()) // this gives {'type': "1SG", 'value': 'n', "series": "I", "position": "S"} when it should give {'type': "1SG", 'value': 'n', "series": "I"}
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Maybe I am wrong in thinking that this kind of data should go in a service? Are services always supposed to update from their components? I would really appreciate any advice or guidance on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use getter function of javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getPronouns(){
    return this.pronouns.map(p => Object.assign({}, p))
}
```

This will return not just a copy of the array but a copy of all its contents. (My previous attempt, this.pronouns.slice(), copies the array but fills it with references to the same objects)

Comment: Hm. I changed the function in the service to returning this.pronouns.slice() but still have the same issue.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Will update answer... I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Objects are mutable and passed by reference. If you want to avoid this, use Observables, in this case `BehaviorSubject` would be appropriate. In your service:

```ts
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

// ...

pronounsArr = [....];

// don't use 'any', type your data! :)
private pronouns: BehaviorSubject<any[]> 
   = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>(this.pronounsArr);
public pronouns$ = this.pronouns.asObservable();
```

Then in components, you can subscribe to this observable:

```ts
constructor (
      public verbService: VerbService, 
      public argumentService: ArgumentService
) {
  argumentService.pronouns$.subscribe(pronouns => {
    console.log(pronouns)
    // do whatever you like...
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked as well but the other solution was all I actually needed.